# How to find the location of MapView Circle on Screen?

Tags: react-native

This function would be called to get the location of circle on 
Button OnPress

```
  const checkPosition = () => {
    circle.measure((fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
      console.log('Component width is: ' + width);
      console.log('Component height is: ' + height);
      console.log('X offset to page: ' + px);
      console.log('Y offset to page: ' + py);
    });
  };
```

Return statement of the Functional Component in React Native

```
          <MapView
                  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                  initialRegion={{
                    latitude: location.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: location.coords.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                  }} style={styles.mapStyle}>

                  <Circle
                    ref={circle}
                    center={area}
                    radius={radius}
                    draggable
                    fillColor="rgba(112, 181, 44, 0.52)"
                    strokeColor="rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.52)"
                  />
        </MapView>
     <View style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 10, width: "100%", 
       justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Button onPress={checkPosition} title="Submit"></Button>
      </View>
    </View>
```

Complete code and Link to Snack:
https://snack.expo.io/@fahad492/mapview-issue

Comment: Has not a ```ref``` prop?

Comment: check the link to snack for complete code